# MUI Grid - Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll

Tags: css, material-ui, react-tsx

I'm trying to do exactly the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll) post but with the implementation on a MUI Grid container/item. The result though is that I don't have a scrollbar and I can't scroll. Is there something wrong with my implementation?

Here is the [codebox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/scrollable-grid-8jrc3n?file=%2Fsrc%2FScrollableGrid.tsx%3A8%2C46)

Thanks in advance for your time.

Edit, apparently the links are working so I'm altering this post with both the links and the code.

Links:

1. [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll)
2. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/scrollable-grid-8jrc3n?file=%2Fsrc%2FScrollableGrid.tsx

Code:

```
const ScrollableGrid: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Grid
      container
      sx={{ overflow: "hidden", maxHeight: "300px", border: "1px solid green" }}
    >
      <Grid
        item
        xs={12}
        sx={{
          overflowY: "auto",
          height: "100%",
          boxSizing: "content-box",
          border: "1px solid red",
          margin: "10px",
        }}
      >
        <div>Text 1</div>
        <br />
        <div>Text 2</div>
        <br />
        <div>Text 3</div>
        <br />
        <div>Text 4</div>
        <br />
        <div>Text 5</div>
        <br />
        <div>Text 6</div>
        <br />
        <div>Text 7</div>
        <br />
        <div>Text 8</div>
        <br />
        <div>Text 9</div>
        <br />
        <div>Text 10</div>
        <br />
        <div>Text 11</div>
        <br />
        <div>Text 12</div>
        <br />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

Comment: The link not found.

Comment: Without the code link working I wouldn't be able to provide more help, but in the past I've used something like `.HideScrollbar {
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
}
.HideScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}`

Comment: Just made the codebox public. Sorry for that.

Comment: That's great I'll add an answer for you when I can (Y)

Answer (score 1):

As my comment worked, I'm adding this for other users.

You can hide the scrollbar but keep the functionality like so:

```css
.HideScrollbar {
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
}
.HideScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/scrollable-grid-8jrc3n?file=%2Fsrc%2FScrollableGrid.tsx&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt62ao8t0007356l2r5ahapp%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt62ao8s0003356lh0084bdo%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt62ao8s0004356ldnyiw6n9%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt62ao8s0006356lx86s2qfm%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B43.13370500220319%252C56.86629499779681%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clt62ao8s0003356lh0084bdo%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt62ao8s0003356lh0084bdo%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clt62ao8s0006356lx86s2qfm%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt62ao8s0005356lsj04nfy8%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt62ao8s0006356lx86s2qfm%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt62ao8s0005356lsj04nfy8%2522%257D%252C%2522clt62ao8s0004356ldnyiw6n9%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt62ao8s0004356ldnyiw6n9%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

[image: Edit scrollable-grid (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the scrollbar by adding the following to index.css or your root CSS file.

```css
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.example::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.example {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

And use the CSS classname in your div.

```
<div className="example">
  <-- Content goes here -->
</div>
```